# Multiple fields with add_settings_field callback

Tags: settings-api

I have a settings page where I am creating a UI that changes column widths for a layout template. To customize this on my settings page I am using `do_settings_fields` for output and `add_settings_field` with a callback function that has multiple fields.

My question is this: Is it wrong to use a single callback for multiple settings fields? Everything is working just fine, and this solution is the easiest way for me to achieve what I need.

Comment: From a coding/DRY perspective, your approach is just fine (and I use that same approach); however, as-written, this question is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: That is great. I saw [this approach][1] while writing my question, but it seems a little overkill to have multiple `add_settings_field`s.   [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116082/single-callback-with-multiple-setting-fields?rq=1

Comment: [Here's how I handle it](https://github.com/chipbennett/oenology/blob/master/functions/options-register.php). You may find it helpful. I have only one call to `add_settings_section()` and `add_settings_field()`, and only one callback for each data type.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the fields do. If they are all of the same type – a label and a text input for example – then, yes, that’s a good approach. You can just [use the sixth parameter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116089/73) to create a different output.

But if these fields are different, need different escaping methods (`esc_textarea()` versus `esc_attr()`) and different HTML code, then you should use different callbacks.

Let’s say you have [stored your data in an array](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100137/73).

Now you have a function or a method in your controller class to create a data object and multiple view objects for the different outputs:

```
class Settings_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $data       = new Settings_Data( 'wpse_123635' ); // option name
        $textarea   = new Textarea( $data, 's1' ); // data plus field id
        $checkbox   = new Checkbox( $data, 's2' );
        $text_field = new Text_field( $data, 's3' );

        add_settings_field(
            's1',
            'A textarea',
            array ( $textarea, 'render' ),
            'my_page',
            'my_section'
        );

        add_settings_field(
            's2',
            'A textarea',
            array ( $checkbox, 'render' ),
            'my_page',
            'my_section'
        );

        add_settings_field(
            's3',
            'A textarea',
            array ( $text_field, 'render' ),
            'my_page',
            'my_section'
        );
    }
}
```

The [views will get their data now from the model](http://r.je/views-are-not-templates.html) `$data`. They are separately testable, reusable and nicely decoupled. You can use the same view class for multiple fields with other data providers and so on.

When in doubt, keep it simple. But if you realize one function has to do too much, separate its tasks.